# What does "We made this" imply here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The scene is in the office in a film.

The boss says

> "We made this."

I don't understand what he wants to say.

Could anybody help me understand it?

Comment: There's no enough context to be sure, but SegNerd's answer is likely correct. We'd need to see body language or what happens before and after to be more confident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The editor is pointing out the fact that the magazine has achieved its goal of appealing to men and expressing pride in that fact.